# Mysql order by two columns having ENUM type

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a doctors table where i have many columns, like `id, name, email,` etc. and two of them is `is_featured` and `is_top`.

These both column type is `ENUM` having value either 'y' or 'n'.

I want to get the doctors first having `is_features='y'` and then those doctors having `is_top='y'` and last `is_featured='n'` and `is_top='n'`

so basically i want the order of the doctors like these:

1. `is_featured='y'`
2. `is_top='y'`
3. `is_featured='n'`
4. `is_top='n'`

Can any one help how can i achieve this?

I am totally unaware about how to syntax these type of sql query?

Comment: It is better to use TINYINT(1) with values 1 and 0 for TRUE and FALSE, respectively, so the value gets casted to boolean correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a shortcut form for that in mysql:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY    is_featured = 'y' DESC,
            is_top = 'y' DESC,
            is_featured = 'n' DESC,
            is_top = 'n' DESC
```

Otherwise, if you want to make it standard which will run in other RDBMS as well, use `CASE`

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY    CASE WHEN is_featured = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
            CASE WHEN is_top='y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
            CASE WHEN is_featured='n' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
            CASE WHEN is_top='n' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
```